# Date and time not same as field date

Tags: 8, datetime

I create a field with date format for my content and I set date and time:

2017-12-23 21:45:36

Now when I want to print with these codes:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    $date = $variables['node']->get('myfieldname')->value;
    $variables['date'] = $date ;
}
```

or

```
{% set date = node.myfieldname.value %}
```

and use {{ date }} in my template, print:

2017-12-23T17:15:36

( 4:30 minutes difference )

How can I fix it in Drupal 8?

Comment: That seems to be a timezone issue. Check your website and server timezones.

Comment: I use it in localhost and time is set correctly

Comment: I do not know your experience level, but just because your computer time is right does not automatically mean your webserver timezone is right. The `php.ini` file can define a timezone as well, offsetting the time from your system time.

Comment: I try but not work. For what I set the time but in print change !!

Comment: This is a timezone issue, but not a configuration issue. It's about how the date is stored in the database. The date field is stored in UTC and if you get the raw value you get UTC. Use the computed property `->date` instead, which has methods to process the date, either `getTimeStamp()` for the Unix timestamp to use php date functions or `format()` for printing a formatted date.

Comment: You should use the formatted date, the date formatters take care of displaying it in the right timezone, e.g. content.myfieldname or content.myfieldname.0 instead of accessing the raw value son node